# Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php

Here's my function:

```
function get_fname($un){

$registerquery = $this->conn->query("SELECT f_name FROM tz_members WHERE 
                     usr='".$un."'");

while ($row = $registerquery->fetch_assoc()) { 
    return $fname = $row[$un];
    }
}
```

### Edit:

I chose to answer my own question because it has an editor.

@Mark Baker:

```
<?php
    require_once 'Mysql.php'; 
    $mysql = new Mysql(); 

?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h4><?php echo $mysql->get_fname("joann"); ?></h4>
  </body>
</html>
```

That's how I am doing it...

Comment: Dang I am going crazy. The query can't seem to grab a result hence the error. However, upon trying your solution, I got no error now but still without a result. I tried the query in phpmyadmin and I got a result. What could be causing this? 

Here's the statement that triggers the function:

<?php echo $mysql->get_fname("joann"); ?><

Comment: Can you please remove your solution from the question, then add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your query failed. Because in that case `query` returns *false*. So try this:

```
$registerquery = $this->conn->query("SELECT f_name FROM tz_members WHERE 
                 usr='".$un."'");
if ($registerquery) {
    while ($row = $registerquery->fetch_assoc()) { 
        return $fname = $row[$un];
    }
}
```

The failure may be caused by a syntax error in your query when `$un` contains characters that break the string declaration (like `'` or `\`). You should use [MySQLi::`real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to escape that characters to prevent that.

Additionally, a function can only return a value once. So the `while` will be aborted after the first row.

Answer (score 1):

$fname = $row[$un]; is assigning the value in $row[$un] to the variable $fname, then returning the result.
It's pointless doing that assignment to $fname because $fname is simply a local variable within the function.... if it's defined as global, then it's not good programming practise.

If echo $mysql->get_fname("joann") is the line where you're calling the get_fname() function, then how are you setting $mysql?

And what do you think will happen if the database query doesn't find any valid result for the query?

Comment: Ok I will change it to global. But the problem is in the query itself. It can't seem to connect to the database. I tried other functions that are working for other queries, still they're not working. 

Here's the thing, I am building a membership site... All query functions are working if I haven't logged in yet. But after I logged in, say I have index.php as the page I am redirected once logged in, and then run a query from there, the functions can't seem to connect to the database. At first I thought it was because of WP, but then when I tried pure thml files, it's still not working???

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = fetch_assoc($registerquery)) { 
    return $fname = $row[$un];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you forgot to give a table name in the connection?

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'ANY VALUE HERE??');