# Prepared statement and retrieving selected value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having trouble retrieving the value from a from database using prepared statement with the following code:

```
`$conn=new
mysqli("localhost","username","password","DBname");
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT tag_name FROM tag WHERE tag_name LIKE '%?%' ORDER BY tag_name LIKE '?%',tag_name LIKE '%?%', tag_id DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $search, $search, $search);
$result=$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '$row["tag_name"];
}`
```

When I look into errorlog of my server, it says "umber of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement", but the number of question marks and the number of variables in the bind_param function are matched, so I really have no idea how to fix this. Does anyone know how to get this thing working?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the question marks inside of a string, like you have here, the SQL parser will not see them as parameters in your query. It instead assumes they are a part of the string literal value, which would explain the parameter/query mismatch.

To do what you're trying to do here (concatenate additional values to your value before escaping them) you will need to do that to the bounded variable or variable param passed through `bind_param` instead.

```
$conn=new
mysqli("localhost","username","password","DBname");
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT tag_name FROM tag
                      WHERE tag_name LIKE ?
                      ORDER BY tag_name LIKE ?,
                               tag_name LIKE ?,
                               tag_id DESC
                      LIMIT 5");
/* Modify values for wildcard search here */
$search1 = "%$search%";
$search2 = "$search%";
$search3 = "%$search%";
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $search1, $search2, $search3);
$result=$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row["tag_name"];
}
```

The difference is the SQL parser can actually properly detect values from code in your query, which is exactly what you wanted. Otherwise you're back to the old *concatenate values in a string and run them through [`mysqli::real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string)* way of doing things.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. I tried your code, and now it is not giving me the "nubmer of variables don't match" error, but instead, I am getting error saying "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object." Do you have any idea why it's telling me this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2840779/1878262 most likely you have some syntax error in your SQL that caused the prepared statement to fail or it failed for some other reason. See the manual on [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) as well for details on how to get error information if it fails.